# MonoGame Window Freezes on drag

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm working on a networked game in MonoGame and have run into the issue of the game freezing whenever the window is dragged. In searching for a solution, I found [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51376/how-do-i-prevent-xna-from-pausing-updates-while-the-window-is-being-resized-move) which describes how to inject a custom tick system.

However, while this answer works for XNA, the required reflection calls throw a exception in MonoGame. Does anyone have an alternative solution that will allow the game to continue to update while it is being dragged?

The code section that throws an exception is:

```
// Exception on this line
object host = typeof(Game).GetField("host", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(this);
host.GetType().BaseType.GetField("Suspend", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(host, null);
host.GetType().BaseType.GetField("Resume", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(host, null);
```

The exception is as follows:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in CardCatacombs.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

With reference, as far as I can tell, to the "host" field of Game.

Comment: "the required reflection calls throw a exception in MonoGame" which exception? what does your code for this look like?

Comment: possibly what you're looking for: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/68914/issue-with-monogame-resizing

Comment: I've updated my question with more information. Unfortunately, the second post refers to graphical scaling, not game logic updating.

Comment: The exception is because there is no longer a `host` field on the `Game` object. This could mean that the first step of unhooking `Suspend` and `Resume` is unnecessary. Have you tried setting up the timer without doing this first part?

Comment: In trying to implement the timer, I've noticed that MonoGame doesn't allow for the use of the System.Windows.Form.Timer class. When I try to call Tick() from within the timer elapsed event (using a System.Timers.Timer), a "NullReferenceException" error is thrown from within Tick()

Comment: You just need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`. Testing it, it seems to work. Not sure about your null reference exception, but it might go away if you use the other timer. I can get my window stretching a graphic while I resize.

Comment: I don't have access to System.Windows.Forms, which leads me to believe that I need an additional assembly. Have you added any additional assemblies to MonoGame beyond the base project setup?

Comment: That's what I mean, add a reference. (Solution Explorer -> Your Project -> References -> Right Click -> Add Reference)

Comment: That seems to work! It may cause issues for cross-platform exporting, but that may take some additional research.

Comment: K I've gotten a version working without windows forms. (Although in Mono apparently there still is a windows forms namespace, even on linux, although it's not perfect.) I'll post what I have as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved by importing the System.Windows.Forms assembly in the project's references and ignoring the reflection component of the provided answer for XNA, as MonoGame no longer uses the "host" field within Game.

Thanks to Sahuagin for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answer, and using `System.Timers.Timer` instead of `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`:

```
public class MyGame : Game {
   bool manualTick;
   int manualTickCount = 0;
   Timer mTimer;

   public MyGame() {
      mTimer = new Timer {
         Interval = (int)(TargetElapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds)
      };

      mTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) => {
         if (manualTickCount > 2) {
            manualTick = true;
            Debug.Print("manual tick");
            Tick();
            manualTick = false;
         }

         manualTickCount++;
      };

      // required to prevent exception on exit
      // otherwise the timer keeps running after the window closes
      Exiting += (s, e) => mTimer.Dispose();

      // it might be needed to do something similar in the Dispose event
      // if the game can be disposed without exiting
   }

   // the constructor is too early to start the timer, so put it in initialize
   protected override void Initialize() {
      mTimer.Start();
      base.Initialize();
   }

   // and lastly, in Update
   protected override void Update(GameTime pGameTime) {
      if (!manualTick) {
         manualTickCount = 0;
         Debug.Print("not manual");
      }
      base.Update(pGameTime);
   }
```